# Google-API Calendar Feed for Java

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm currently using the new Google API 1.5 beta, and I can't find any examples for retrieving a calendar feed. The examples posted [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) only seem to provide a list of calendars per account and not their events. Is the old GData API the only way to retrieve a calendar feed right now? And if so, is it worth waiting for this feature to appear in the new API if I only want to retrieve an event feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some digging around in the other non-Android examples and found this to work:

```
CalendarUrl url = new CalendarUrl(calendar.getEventFeedLink());
try {
  EventFeed feed = client.eventFeed().list().execute(url);
  for(EventEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
    // etc....
  }
}
catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```